# How to pass EL/variables between JSF/PF components

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `<p:contentFlow` component which I use to show some images rendered with `DefaultStreamedContent`. there is a `<p:commandButton` inside of each `.item` of the `contentFlow` component and when this button is clicked, a `dialog` is invoked to render The `.active` image in bigger dimensions.

Right now the image information is being extracted from the `contentFlow` to the `dialog` via javascript  which I believe it to be a bit rudimentary and on top of this, when I call the `iteration variable` in the `contentFlow var="i"` I keep on getting what seems to be the last `state` of the variable (last image).

¿What would be the correct way to pass information between `JSF/PF` components to be able to use the bean information say to delete the selected image amongst  other things?

So basically what is the easiest way to pass the `i.id` from the **active or current** image in the `<p:contentFlow` component to a `<p:outputLabel` *inside* of a `<p:dialog` that pops up when a inside `.item` class is clicked ?

from:

```
<p:contentFlow value="#{fileUploadMB.personalImgList}" var="i" id="contentFlow" styleClass="contentWrapp">                                                                                                        

  <p:graphicImage value="#{fileUploadMB.image}"  styleClass="content"
                onclick="clickFlow(this, event)"                                                                                
                title="Utilice Scroll,Flechas o Arrastre las imagenes">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{i.id}"/>                                

    <div id="image-options">
        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrow-4-diag"
                         oncomplete="PF('imageDialog').show()"                                                 
                         onclick="modal(this)">
            <input type="hidden" value="#{i.id}" id="AII"/>                                        
        </p:commandButton>         
    </div>                                
  </p:graphicImage>                               
  <div class="caption">#{i.imageName}</div>                                                     
</p:contentFlow>
```

to

```
<p:dialog resizable="false" 
          fitViewport="true"
          widgetVar="imageDialog"
          style="height: 95vh;width: 95vw;"
          id="imageDialogForm"
          modal="true" 
          showEffect="clip" 
          hideEffect="slide"
          closeOnEscape="true"> 
    <p:layout style="height: 90vh; width: 90vw;" >
        <p:layoutUnit position="center" collapsible="true" gutter="0">
            <h:graphicImage value="" width="80%" styleClass="image-lightboxer"/>                                        
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="15%" gutter="0" collapsible="true" style="text-align: right;">
            <h:form prependId="false">
                           <!-- how to pass to these labels
                           // the ACTIVE  image
                           //which has class type .active
                           // which is always showing the same information
                           // which turns out to be the las [i] variable                     
                           //info from the  contentFlow  var="i" -->
                <p:outputLabel value="#{i.activeImageId}"/>
                <p:separator/>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{i.imageName}"/>
                <p:separator/>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{i.imageDescription}"/>
                <p:separator/>
                <p:commandButton value="Eliminar Foto" icon="ui-icon-trash" iconPos="right"
                                 onclick="PF('imageDialog').hide()"
                                 oncomplete="PF('delImg').show()"/>
            </h:form>       

        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</p:dialog>
```

Or  if  I'm just complicating this too much, any other solutions gladly taken. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So In order to get the **current/active** image when the `commandButton` was click, I had to use `js`, set a *new* activeImage `variable` in the managed bean and update the `dialog form` which contained the information of the image clicked.

**This is my solution, if anyone has a better one it'd be apreciated a lot.**

So what I did was  in the content flow, call a `js` function on the `onClick` event:

```
<p:contentFlow value="#{fileUploadMB.personalImgList}"
               var="i" id="contentFlow"
               styleClass="contentWrapp">                                                                                                        

    <p:graphicImage value="#{fileUploadMB.image}"  styleClass="content"
                    onclick="clickFlow(this, event)"                                                                                
                    title="Utilice Scroll,Flechas o Arrastre las imagenes">
        <f:param name="id" value="#{i.id}"/>                                

        <div id="image-options">
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrow-4-diag"
                             oncomplete="PF('imageDialog').show()"                                                 
                             onclick="modal(this)"> <!-- this is the js function -->
                <input type="hidden" value="#{i.id}" id="AII"/>                                        
            </p:commandButton>         
        </div>                                
    </p:graphicImage>                               
    <div class="caption">#{i.imageName}</div>                                                     
</p:contentFlow>
```

In the `onclick="modal(this)"`  function I verified the `.active` status of the clicked button *related* to the image and extracted the image information and with this information, I set the attributes of the `<p:graphicImage` and `<p:outputLabel`'s  inside of the `<p:dialog` component.

```
function modal(item) {
    if ($(item).parent().parent().hasClass('active')) {
        var src = $(item).parent().siblings('canvas').attr('src');
        $('.image-lightboxer:first-child').attr('src', src);
        var x = $('.active #image-options #AII').val();
        $("#aiin").val(x);
        $("#aibtn").click();
    }
}
```

Created a separate `<h:form` that was `style="display:none"` includding all of its children. This form would be used to pass the information extracted in the `modal(item)`  *js* function  to a `managed bean` variable which would contain all the required information for future purpuses like `CRUD` based operations:

```
<h:form  prependId="false" style="display: none;">
    <h:inputText binding="#{ai}" id="aiin" style="display: none;"/>
    <p:commandButton  id="aibtn" value="aiii" action="#{fileUploadMB.ai(ai.value)}"
                      style="display: none;"
                      update="aiiform"/>
</h:form>
```

The `<p:commandButton id="aibtn"` is clicked through `js` function so at this point the variable in  `managed bean` is set and the dialog is shown with its proper information:

```
<p:dialog resizable="false" 
          fitViewport="true"
          widgetVar="imageDialog"
          style="height: 95vh;width: 95vw;"
          id="imageDialogForm"
          modal="true" 
          showEffect="clip" 
          hideEffect="slide"
          closeOnEscape="true"> 
    <p:layout style="height: 90vh; width: 90vw;" >
        <p:layoutUnit position="center" collapsible="true" gutter="0">
            <h:graphicImage value="" width="80%" styleClass="image-lightboxer"/>                                        
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="15%" gutter="0" collapsible="true" style="text-align: left;">
            <h:form prependId="false" id="aiiform">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{fileUploadMB.activeUserImage.id}"/>
                <p:separator/>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{fileUploadMB.activeUserImage.imageName}"/>
                <p:separator/>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{fileUploadMB.activeUserImage.imageDescription}"/>
                <p:separator/>
                <p:commandButton value="Eliminar Foto" icon="ui-icon-trash" iconPos="right"
                                 onclick="PF('imageDialog').hide()"
                                 oncomplete="PF('delImg').show()"/>
            </h:form>       

        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</p:dialog>
```